# Facelets Parameter has no value when passed to another page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a case like this where I include one file in another. but the page is more complex..
I sometimes get #{param2} with no value while #{param1} with a value. I even named the param some random name just to make sure there's no other param anywhere else with the same name that could be overwriting it.

Why could this happen, a ui:param who's value is overwritten by blank somehow?

In the first xhtml we include another file:

```
<ui:include src="/myFile.xhtml">    
    <ui:param name="param1"     value="stringvalue1" />
    <ui:param name="param2"     value="stringvalue2" />
</ui:include>
```

myFile.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/seam/faces"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    #{param1}
    #{param2}
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: The code given so far looks fine. Do you mean to say that exactly this code will fail with a blank for `#{param2}` when copypasted into a blank environment? There are of course reserved identifiers in EL like `#{param}`, but you don't seem to use any of them.

Comment: I meant to say that I have some pages that pass parameters in this way... Some of the pages are too complex. "Includes" are inside loops for example. Or the same component is included multiple times in the page in different locations. I am not using anything that can be a reserved word. Is there anything else that could cause a value to be blank

Comment: I fixed the problem.. For the record here's how I fixed it... And maybe someone can explain the behavior...  I am including a component in 2 places on a page... In the first include param2 is not passed because we want it to be blank. In the second include param2 is passed with value "value2". The fix was in the first include to put param2 with a "" value: <ui:param name="param2"     value="" />